# why threading not working?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, parallel-processing

here is my code:

```
using System;

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;

using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.IO;
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;

namespace CopyFile
{
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        long length = 0;
        byte[] buffer;
        string source_path, dest_path;
        source_path = Console.ReadLine();
        dest_path = Console.ReadLine();
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(source_path);
        length = (int)fi.Length;
        // Create disk file
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(dest_path))
        {
            fs.Close();
        }
        // Create unnamed MMF
        var mmf1 = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(source_path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, null, length);
        // Create reader to MMF
        var reader = mmf1.CreateViewAccessor(0, length, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read);
        // Create unnamed MMF
        var mmf2 = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(dest_path, FileMode.Create, null, length);
        // Create writer to MMF
        var writer = mmf2.CreateViewAccessor(0, length, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Write);

        int read_block = int.Parse(Math.Min(length, 512 * 1024).ToString());//4k
        int end_read_block = int.Parse(length.ToString()) % read_block;

        int[] offset_array = new int[int.Parse((length - read_block).ToString()) / read_block];
        for (int offset = 0,i=0; i < int.Parse((length - read_block).ToString()) / read_block; i++,offset += read_block)
        {
            offset_array[i] = offset;
        }

        /*
        Parallel.ForEach<int>(offset_array, offset =>
        {
            // Read from MMF
            buffer = new byte[read_block];
            reader.ReadArray<byte>(offset, buffer, 0, read_block);
            // Write to MMF
            writer.WriteArray<byte>(offset, buffer, 0, read_block);
        });
         */
        foreach (int offset in offset_array)
        {
            // Read from MMF
            buffer = new byte[read_block];
            reader.ReadArray<byte>(offset, buffer, 0, read_block);
            // Write to MMF
            writer.WriteArray<byte>(offset, buffer, 0, read_block);
        }

        buffer = new byte[end_read_block];
        reader.ReadArray<byte>(length - end_read_block, buffer, 0, end_read_block);
        // Write to MMF
        writer.WriteArray<byte>(length - end_read_block, buffer, 0, end_read_block);

    }
}
}
```

i try to copy one file and paste it in another location
it is working

but when i try to use Parallel.foreach or Parallel.for when it copy one file 
copied file is different with source file

(I commented Parallel.foreach section)

i can't understand why

thanks

Comment: How would it work? You're going to be writing to the file out of order if you have multiple threads writing to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code;

```
Parallel.ForEach<int>(offset_array, offset =>
{
    // Read from MMF
    buffer = new byte[read_block];
    reader.ReadArray<byte>(offset, buffer, 0, read_block);
    // Write to MMF
    writer.WriteArray<byte>(offset, buffer, 0, read_block);
});
```

`buffer` is a shared variable, so all threads will share it. For example, thread 1 will assign buffer, read from the file, thread 2 will reassign buffer and read the file, thread 1 will write the contents of thread 2's buffer.

To make it work better, have buffer be a local variable in the loop, a'la;

```
Parallel.ForEach<int>(offset_array, offset =>
{
    // Read from MMF
    byte[] buffer = new byte[read_block];
    reader.ReadArray<byte>(offset, buffer, 0, read_block);
    // Write to MMF
    writer.WriteArray<byte>(offset, buffer, 0, read_block);
});
```

That will allow all threads to have their own, local, buffer.

Looking at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267585) though makes things look bleak, any instance method (ReadArray/WriteArray) are not guaranteed to be thread safe. In other words, even if you fix the buffer problem, there is no guarantee that things will work.

Comment: Essential problem with his code that he is trying to copy file faster by using multiple threads to access same data stream. While your answer points to one problem, it does not solve the bigger one.

Comment: @NikolaRadosavljević While unlikely, this is a memory mapped file we're reading/writing. If pages are paged out, having another thread take over and copy the next page while waiting for pagein may actually speed up the operation. Agreed in practice though, this will probably not speed anything up much.

Comment: @NikolaRadosavljević Updated my answer after reading your input and double checking the documentation. Good call.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to copying a file is not good. Beside problem which Joachim Isaksson described, problem is that you are accessing file streams from multiple threads at the same time. This means that it could happen that one thread T1 reads data, then scheduler passes control to thread T2 which reads data and then writes it to destination. When control is returned to T1 and it writes read data, you will get a corrupt file.
There is no reason to use concurrency to copy a file as CPU is not bottleneck for this operation. You will not get faster results, you will only waste CPU cycles.